# Does Messenger really requires calling Unscribe

Tags: xamarin.forms

I see `Messenger` uses `WeakReference` to store references to event emitters and event listeners:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/MessagingCenter.cs

Is calling `Unscribe` still necessary to avoid memory leaks?

I think I hit a situation on Android where it really looks like I must call it, otherwise I have a memory leak.

To check for a potential memory leak, I added the deconstructor to both view-model and view and I call `GC.Collect` on `OnDisappearing` on the `Page`, and the deconstructors do not get called unless I call `Unscribe`.

**EDIT**: After a closer inspection I see `Messenger` also stores the `Action` callback passed to `Messenger.Subscribe()`, but without using a `WeakReference` !

See https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/MessagingCenter.cs#L107

I am confused, why isn't it using a `WeakReference` also for storing the `Action`!? Because it's obvious it's going to leak unless I call `Unscribe`

Comment: @BraveHeart I don't follow you. What would it be implemented sooner or later?

Comment: Oh sorry I got your question wrong.

Comment: @JameL you should be able to write a unit test and see if there is an issue or not. They are using `WeakReference` on the object, but not the `Action`, so it might be fine. Use the technique I posted here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/279#issuecomment-255213497

Comment: @jonathanpeppers but most of the time the Action implementation is using objects from the view-model implementation. So Messenger ends up keeping view-model instance alive, and so on. Wouldn't using a WeakReference for holding Action had eliminated the need to call Unscribe? Which I think it makes using Messenger easier. You could still call Unscribe in cases you want to to unscribe earlier than page or view-model's lifetime.

Comment: On a 2nd thought, since the GC doesn't immediately garbage-collects a page/view-model anyway, I guess it makes sense to always call Unscribe just to be sure there's no message processing after navigating away from the page?

Comment: I think it's best practice to unsubscribe when you can. In `Pages` you have `OnDisappearing`, `Views` you can use `OnParentSet` and check that `Parent` is null. You can call out to `ViewModels` here as well, since they won't get the same lifecycle events.